# geometry setting text block but not page dimensions

Tags: pdftex, luatex, geometry

I'm utterly stumped by this.  Here is my file:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\title{My Title}
\author{Me}
\date{}

\usepackage[a5paper,outer=0.5in,inner=0.5in,lines=39,
    includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

When I compile this with `lualatex`, I get the correct size text block, but the page dimensions remain letterpaper (which is the default on my TeXLive 2016 system).  When I compile it with `pdflatex`, however, I get the correct page dimensions as well as the correct textblock.  To illustrate:  on the left is the `lualatex` output, to the right is the `pdflatex` output.  I've had imagemagick draw a border to make the page dimensions clear.

[image: lualatex output]
[image: pdflatex output]

Any thoughts on what's going on here and how to fix it?

Comment: Add `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` before the  \documentclass command.

Comment: Well, that was easy; thanks.  What's going on internally here?

Comment: luatex starting from version 0.85 no longer defines \pdfpagewidth and so geometry doesn't set it. The package provides a suitable definition. (Naturally it would be better, if geometry would correct its code, but hasn't done it yet).

Comment: Got it; thanks. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

luatex starting from version 0.85 no longer defines `\pdfpagewidth` and so geometry doesn't set it.

Add `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` before the `\documentclass` command
The package provides a suitable definition and then geometry will behave again.